# open email by php using imap giving me this error Message: imap_open() [function.imap-open]: Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX

Tags: php, html, css, email, imap

I am trying to open the email messages by php using imap method but it give me an error Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX and this is my code

```
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'nohamedtemraz92@gmail.com';
$password = '0129799169mohamed';

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username ,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: '        imap_last_error());

    /* grab emails */
    $emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');

    /* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
    if($emails) {

        /* begin output var */
        $output = '';

        /* put the newest emails on top */
        rsort($emails);

        /* for every email... */
        foreach($emails as $email_number) {

            /* get information specific to this email */
            $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);


            $output.= 'Name:  '.$overview[0]->from.'</br>';
                $output.= 'Email:  '.$overview[0]->message_id.'</br>';



        }

        echo $output;
    } 

 /* close the connection */
imap_close($inbox);
```

Comment: this may be a firewall issue. just disable the firewall and test the code.

Comment: I hope those aren't credentials for an important account.  You should change your password.   It seems most web hosts that people attempt to run their PHP on have IMAP firewalled by default.

Comment: Checked) Password was changed 3 months ago :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username ,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: '        imap_last_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX
```

working for me but you have to enable 'Access for less secure apps' on account security or you can try live email account